Navigation Properties with Many-to-Many Relations
With a one-to-many relation, I can use navigation properties when creating a new entity.
public class Team
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public List<Player>? Players { get; set; } = null!;
}

public class Player
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public Guid TeamGuid { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(TeamGuid))]
    public Team? Team { get; set; } = null!;
}

This is nice because I can add a Player to a Team by just specifying the Team key. However, I'm having trouble extending this approach to a many-to-many relation. For example, I tried this:
public class Team
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public List<Guid>? PlayerGuids { get; set; } = null!;
    [ForeignKey(nameof(PlayerGuids))]
    public List<Player>? Players { get; set; } = null!;
}

public class Player
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public List<Guid>? TeamGuids { get; set; } = null!;
    [ForeignKey(nameof(TeamGuids))]
    public List<Team>? Teams { get; set; } = null!;
}

EF Core seemed to just ignore my navigation properties. Is there a way to make this approach work with a many-to-many relation?

My mistake on the EF Core 3 tag. I meant EF Core 8.0.

Use join entity. There are many samples in the doc

With EF-Core 6+, it would be very easy, just like that:
public class Team
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public List<Player>? Players { get; set; } = null!;
}

public class Player
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public List<Team>? Teams { get; set; } = null!;
}


Yes. This is what I am currently doing. I'm wondering if there is a way to use navigation properties.

Teams in Player and Players in Team are already Navigation Properties. If you really using EF core 3, it might not be supported. Update your EF Core Version to a newer version.

Player.Teams and Team.Players are already navigation properties. What I believe you are confused about are how Foreign Keys work in relational databases when it comes to many-to-many relationships. They are done using a linking table For instance:
PlayerTeams
    - (PK/FK) PlayerGuid 
    - (PK/FK) TeamGuid

As far as the entities themselves go, you don't need to directly use a PlayerTeam in the relationship as long as there is no additional information you need about the relationship itself. For example you can have:
public class Team
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Player> Players { get; protected set; } = [];
}

public class Player
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public List<Team> Teams { get; protected set; } = [];
}

A couple recommendations is that when it comes to collection navigation properties, use protected setters and initialize those collections. This prevents code from doing something "dangerous" like setting a collection on an existing entity to a new set. When it comes to adjusting the related data you want to add and remove items from the associated set, not replace the set.
The tricky bit can be linking the two up. EF can wire up relationships that follow certain naming and structure conventions, but I recommend explicit configuration to avoid surprises when assumptions don't work. The easiest thing is to define a joining entity:
public class PlayerTeam
{
    public Guid PlayerId { get; set; }
    public Guid TeamId { get; set; }

    public virtual Player? Player { get; protected set; }
    public virtual Team? Team { get; protected set; }
}

Then when configuring the Player entity:
void IEntityTypeConfiguration<Player>.Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Player> builder)
{
    builder.HasMany(x => x.Teams)
        .WithMany(x => x.Players)
        .UsingEntity<PlayerTeam>(
            l => l.HasOne(x => x.Team).WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey("TeamGuid"),
            r => r.HasOne(x => x.Player).WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey("PlayerGuid));
}

Where the relationship changes is if you want additional information about the relationship. For example if you wanted to record the start / end dates of when a player was playing for a team. This is a column that would exist in the PlayerTeam and as such we would have to update the relationship to include the PlayerTeam:
public class Team
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public virtual List<PlayerTeam> PlayerTeams { get; protected set; } = [];
}

public class Player
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public List<PlayerTeam> PlayerTeams { get; protected set; } = [];
}

public class PlayerTeam
{
    public Guid PlayerId { get; set; }
    public Guid TeamId { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Player? Player { get; protected set; }
    public virtual Team? Team { get; protected set; }
}

Note that since the relationship now uses PlayerTeams, if you want to select the teams themselves for a player (or vice-versa) you have to do it through the PlayerTeam. The relationship configuration in this case simplifies to:
void IEntityTypeConfiguration<Player>.Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Player> builder)
{
    builder.HasMany(x => x.PlayerTeams)
        .WithRequired(x => x.Player);
}

void IEntityTypeConfiguration<Team>.Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TEam> builder)
{
    builder.HasMany(x => x.PlayerTeams)
        .WithRequired(x => x.Team);
}

void IEntityTypeConfiguration<PlayerTEam>.Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Player> builder)
{   // Needed for a composite key. If you use a PlayerTeamId in the table you can just annotate it in the entity with [Key]
    builder.HasKey(x => new { x.PlayerGuid, x.TeamGuid });
}

